# Position image in left side of screen <aside>

Tags: html

I would like to position my text and an image side-by-side. Right now, the text is to the left of the image. To move the text to the right, I can change the position of

```
<aside>
```

How do I move the image to the left though?

```
<aside style="background-image: url(img/s-esh_spectrogram.jpg);"> </aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a wrapper around your sections and set the CSS property `display: flex` on it.
Further reading: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

section.text-section {
  height:     300px;
  width:      60%;
  background: #82fcf5;
}

aside.image-section {
  height:     300px;
  width:      40%;
  background: #c8fc55;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <aside class="image-section" style="background-image: url(img/s-esh_spectrogram.jpg);">
    <p>Image here...</p>
  </aside>

  <section class="text-section">
    <p>Text here...</p>
  </section>

</div>
```